# Internal forward link with add_rewrite_rule

Tags: permalinks

I want to forward a link to another link but internally. I've set up the wordpress to show post links like this - https://asif.bzstage.com/medical/website/nyc/ which only throws 404 error. However If you visit https://asif.bzstage.com/location/website/nyc/ (location instead of medical), it works. So I want to forward any url containing `medical` to `location`.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What's your custom post type slug?

Comment: @filipecsweb `location`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should work for you as long as:

1. Your CPT slug is `location`.
2. You don't have a custom `query_var` registered for your CPT `location`. You probably don't have. Refer to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#query_var for more information, it's very usefull, btw.

And I'm assuming the string `nyc` is the slug of your single custom post.

```
function rewrite_medical_url() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^medical/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?location=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'rewrite_medical_url' );
```

Put the code in your **functions.php** file.

In order for the rewrite rule start taking effect you should visit **Settings** > **Permalinks** to flush your permalinks.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried the same thing before expect using `+` in it. My custom post is little complicated. This refers to my another question - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/338623/rewrite-cpt-slug-with-two-taxonomy-slug-instead-of-one
Both of the top slugs are actually taxonomies.However putting two `%sector%/%service%` breaks wordpress' normal permalinks. So I am now using  `sector/%service%` while internally forwarding `sector`. If there is a better solution to my question(that I linked in this comment), could you please help me with that?

Comment: I'll take a look at it. Cheers.